# Magento 2 : loading spinner in frontend

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.7

I want to show loading spinner on certain action, like click on particular button will show loading image on the screen.

I know default functionality exist for magento 2. but don't know how to enable it on certain button click.

Thanks